# Can I write my typeorm entities in typescript while having my app writed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, architecture, typeorm

I found it way more intuitive to write typeorm entities in typescript format, however my whole app is indeed in javascript. I know those languages are compiling the same way, but will It cause any kind of problems to do so ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't, if you enable the `"allowJs": true` flag in the `tsconfig.json`, and always compile the typescript codes alongside with the javascript codes.

This is actually recommended, when you would like to migrate your codebase from javascript to typescript **incrementally**.

Comment: Yeah that is actually what I wanted to do later on, gradually converting my codebase from js to ts, I will try to add a tsconfig.json file, because the syntax for javascript entities insn't really much documented.